# Elastic Search Repository in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, repository

I have hosted my elastic search (7.7) instance on AWS, and I am using Springboot version 2.2.
I am trying to create a elastic search repository but i get the error

```
*********
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
*********

Description:

Field elasticSearchRepository in <package> required a bean named 'elasticsearchTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'elasticsearchTemplate' in your configuration.
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489593/consider-defining-a-bean-named-elasticsearchtemplate-in-your-configuration

Comment: You need to configure bean using ```@bean``` annotation for your issue (elasticsearchTemplate) in configuration. Please post your full code, so that it's easy to analyse it.