# Can not use ElasticsearchRepository in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to use `ElasticsearchRepository` for simple CRUD operation. I dont want to use `RestHighLevelClient`. I was following [this tutorials](https://codecurated.com/blog/how-to-connect-java-with-elasticsearch/) 1st method.
Here is my dependancy

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch'
```

And properties in Application.properties

```
spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris=http://192.168.5.212:9200
spring.elasticsearch.rest.connection-timeout=10s
spring.elasticsearch.rest.read-timeout=1m
spring.elasticsearch.rest.username=user
spring.elasticsearch.rest.password=pass
```

Then i just added repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, String> {

}
```

Finally here is my User class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Document(createIndex = false, indexName = "user", type = "_doc")

public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String uid;

    private String name;
}
```

But i am getting the error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-07 10:16:30,497 ERROR [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter:40 - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.user.UserService required a bean named 'elasticsearchTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'elasticsearchTemplate' in your configuration.
```

Tried `#spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled = true`  but still getting error

**N.B This question is not a duplicate of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489593/consider-defining-a-bean-named-elasticsearchtemplate-in-your-configuration) as i am using different method.**

Comment: Please include the full error message.

Comment: @tgdavies not getting any exception just this error message. Please check the updated question

Answer (score 2):

Solved my problem, The issue is my springboot project version is `'2.1.8.RELEASE'`.
The autoconfiguration i am trying to implement requires minimum spring boot version `2.2.0`.
As i can not upgrade spring boot version, i had to add configuration class manually.